# .gitignore file to ignore all files but not nested ones

Tags: git

What should my .gitignore file look like so that all files in the root directory of the repository are ignored but not files in the nested paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in the .gitignore:

```
/*
!/*/
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but it causes problems with the other excludes making the file order sensitive. It is a correct answer though - thanks!